# Helvetica Neue Light with @font-face .. legal?

Tags: css, font-face

My team and I have developed a site using the Helvetica Neue Light font face via @font-face in our stylesheet.

We're curious about whether it's legal for us to do this and who owns that font (if anyone?) Does anyone know how we can find this out - google just shows lots of sites trying to sell us the font.

I understand it's a system font on most mac computers, so maybe its license is pretty open?

Comment: ``I understand it's a system font on most mac computers, so maybe its license is pretty open?`` Now thats a strange assumption :D

Comment: More a hopeful random guess. Hence the question :)

Comment: I may be completely wrong, but if you're not embedding the actual font or serving it as a download and just using it if its a system font for a user wouldn't that be legal?

Comment: The fact that Apple has licensed it for inclusion in Mac OS X does **not** mean that its license is "pretty open". It's still a proprietary font, and that means you can't serve it up as a download on your webpage. Although as @Mark suspects, it's perfectly legal and valid to specify it in CSS as the font to use when the user *does* have it installed on their system.

Comment: Did you find a license to use on web? (I want to server the fonts to be downloaded to the client's computer) All i could find is a PageViews based license for Helvetica. I want a pay-once license

Comment: On Windows 7+ you can use "Segoe UI Light" which is pretty close to Helvetica Neue Light.  just a suggestion.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you are just referencing the users system fonts then the licensing requirement is on the User.

If you are providing the font then you (or your client) will need to licence the Font -- even if it's a free font there will likely be some form of licence.

@font-face uses two forms of reference: **LOCAL** which references the user's system font and **URL** which effectively uses a copy of a font which you provide and as there is very little point in using the @fontface rule if you aren't going to provide the font then it's almost certain that you'll need to actively obtain a licence.

for example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myHelveticaLight;
  src: local("Helvetica Neue Light"),
       local("HelveticaNeue-Light");
}
```

Here you are only referencing a user's installed system font and therefore have no have responsibility for obtaining the licence.

In the following example you are also providing a fallback copy of the font so you must have actively obtained a web licence for that font (or rather your client or the website owner will need to)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myHelveticaLight;
  src: local("Helvetica Neue Light"),
       local("HelveticaNeue-Light"),
       url(HelveticaNeueLight.ttf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,some real good info there. In the end we decided to sign up to http://webfonts.fonts.com just to avoid having the worry and to make life a bit easier. I think there are some other similar services online but that one had the font(s) we were looking for - in this case Helvetica Neue Light

Comment: Actually, Adobe owns that font, just like Remixz has said. Here is the url to the Adobe web page which confirms this claim: http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFont&code=HLNQ10045000

Comment: If i buy the license for 29$ will i be able to server it to clients?

Comment: @uri-abramson If you don't understand the terms of the license, the only party you should have clarify it for you is the licensor or your lawyer.

Answer (score 12):

Apple pays for its system fonts, so the inclusion of a font in Apple's operating systems doesn't tell you much. That particular font is owned by Linotype and sold for profit. A quick Google tells me [fonts.com offers Neue Helvetica Light](http://webfonts.fonts.com/en-US/Project/ChooseFonts?viewFontId=692680&ViewDetails=T) as a Web font, so you might take a look there.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what we did!

Comment: If i buy the license for 29$ will i be able to server it to client browser? I'm asking this because fonts.com call it a Desktop license for some reason and i can't figure out if i can use it woth @font-face (url)

Comment: @UriAbramson: On the box where you buy the font, there are two tabs at the top. Make sure you have "Web Font" selected, because the "Buy Font" option *is* the desktop version.

Comment: But the pricing on Web Fonts is based on PageViews! isn't there a one-time buy and use on website license? i'm asking because i couldn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

Just took a look, and its actually Adobe who owns it, and they sell it for money. So, my *best* guess is no, you couldn't legally use it for free. I have no idea if Adobe licenses it, though. Maybe you could try and find one that's licensed for web use, and is similar to Helvetica?

Answer (score 2):

Embedding it using @font-face would probably be illegal (unless the foundry that owns it has extended their EULAs). Helvetica is pretty widespread as it comes standard with mac and Arial (almost identical) is standard on PCs. If you aren't using any of the more fancy weights that come with Helvetica Neue, I'm sure you could just specify Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif and it would show up fine on most machines.

You could try searching [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) for a substitute, or use images if the font's EULA is restricted. [TypeKit](http://typekit.com/) also offers many classic fonts for web-embedding for a fee. Helvetica is not one of them, but you might request them to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is only one official Helvetica Neue, and, as stated by Chuck, owned by linotype. So, you'll have to ask them. (Last I checked, they don't allow it, but I've since heard they've started opening up some of their font licenses for @font-face use...)

But, in general, you need to read the license of the individual font. That's the only way to know. Even then, licenses can be rather vague, so you usually want to go back to the foundry and ask them directly.

Answer (score 0):

No.

> You may install one copy of the Software on one Computer file server within 
>   your Internal Network for the purpose of downloading and installing the Software on up to the Permitted Number of other Computers within the same Internal Network,

Which is 5 for [this specific license](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/type/font-licensing/EULA5seat-USEnglish07.11.11.pdf).