# HelveticaNeueLite font-face bug in ie 9

Tags: css, html, font-face, embedded-fonts

I am working on a website that requires me to use `HelveticaNeueLite` font-family.
I have separate css files for ie and other browsers.
My css code for ie is as follows

```
@font-face {
font-family: HelveticaNeueLite;
src: url("/system/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-UltLt_0.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

[image]

But I keep getting the above error in ie-9.
I don't know what's going wrong. I donot have reference of any `.otf` font in my css file for ie.
I had used `HelveticaNeueLTStd-UltLt_0.otf` file to generate `HelveticaNeueLTStd-UltLt_0.ttf` through http://www.freefontconverter.com/ and used `HelveticaNeueLTStd-UltLt_0.ttf` to generate `HelveticaNeueLTStd-UltLt_0.eot` through http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi

---

Instead of `.eot` I used `.woff` font, and it worked in IE-9.

```
@font-face {
font-family: HelveticaNeueLite;
src: url('/system/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-UltLt_0.woff') format("woff");
}
```

But I still I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: `.eot` means [Embedded OpenType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_OpenType)

Comment: Have you tried the FontSquirrel tool? http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480504/helvetica-neue-light-with-font-face-legal

Comment: @BenM: I used fontsquirrel. I got a message saying `Adobe has requested that their font Helvetica Neue LT Std 25 Ultra Light be blacklisted by Generator. You will not be able to convert this font.` What does it mean?

Comment: Then you shouldn't use it with @font-face then!

Comment: @BenM : But `@font-face {
 font-family: HelveticaNeueLite;
 src: url("/system/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-UltLt_0.otf") format('opentype');
}`, worked with other browsers

Comment: I know that, but you need to verify that the font is actually allowed for use with @font-face. That's my point. It's like using a copyrighted image.

Comment: @BenM : Thanx for your comment. I'll use another font family then.

Comment: Hi, we decided to **ban** HelveticaNeue and all those Helvetica[neue] font sets. Too buggy and heavy. Unabled to render those fonts correctly.